# Робити щось за гроши у значені "майже задурно"

Tags: фразеологізми, відмінювання

Майже впевнений у крилатому виразі "робити за грош**И**" у значенні "майже задурно". Відрізняється лише однією буквою від "Робити за грош**І**", т.т. за оплату.

У СУМі є [гріш](http://sum.in.ua/s/ghrish)

> **Гріш ціна; Ціна — мідний гріш** — нічого не вартий; нікуди не годиться.
>   Гріш ціна тому генералові, який не знає своїх кращих командирів (Юрій
>   Бедзик, Полки.., 1959, 323); Ціна всяким законам про вибори народних
>   представників — мідний гріш, поки немає фактично завойованого
>   самодержавства народу.. (Ленін, 9, 1949, 164); 
>   **Ламаного гроша не вартий** — не має ніякої цінності; 
>   нічого не вартий. [Клеопатра:] їхні
>   роботи ламаного гроша не варті (Олександр Корнійчук, Чому посміх.
>   зорі, 1958, 74); **Ні на гріш** — нема нічого. Ваших панів-радикалів,
>   окрім двох-трьох людей, я ні за що вважаю.. Правди у них нема ні на
>   гріш, я в них не вірю (Леся Українка, V, 1956, 160);

[Тут](https://svitslova.com/idioms-dictionary/2393-grish-cina.html) є ще пару прикладів

> Цитрон заморський,— гріш йому ціна, коли керсетку он яку червону дають
>   за вузлик прілого пшона. (Ліна Костенко, Маруся Чурай).

Але "робити за грош**И**" [не знайшов](http://stalivyrazy.org.ua/search.php?fullname=%E4%E0%F0%EE%EC&submit=%D8%F3%EA%E0%F2%E8) навіть у російсько-українському словнику фразеологізмів

Тому є сумніви

- Чи не росіянізм це часом?
- Чи вірно я використав *гріш* у множині?
- Чи існує в українській мові такий фразеологізм?

Comment: Зустрічала, вживають у цьому значенні *за копійки* (наголос може бути як на другому, так і на третьому складі). Правда, може, розмовне.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Одразу як побачив питання, то згадав вислів "**робити за безцінь**". Є він і в [СУМі](http://sum.in.ua/s/bezcinj):

> За безцінь, рідко За безцін — дуже дешево, майже дарма.

Згідно до [Орфографічного словника](https://www.slovnyk.ua/index.php?swrd=%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%96%D1%88) - множина від слова "гріш" буде "гроші".

Знаю, що в російській мові є вислів "работать за гроши", тому "робити за гроши" і справді може бути калькою. Взагалі саме слово "гріш" запозичене із старочеської чи давньоверхньонімецької мов (див. [ЕСУМ](http://history.org.ua/LiberUA/EtSlUkrM_1982/EtSlUkrM_1982.pdf), ст.599).